# Get selected title when image is clicked in dropdown

Tags: javascript, html

I am not sure if this is the right approach to achieve this but this is what I have been working with. I have a working dropdown which only has images (which is what I wanted), when I click on an image I want the title value to pass to the function event in my JavaScript code. It is basically a custom smiley set in a dropdown menu which has a vertical scroll bar for screen-space saving. All I ever see if a null or undefined result when using alert() in js. this is the part of the code I am having troubles with.

```js
function emoiconsSelect(event) {
  // get value of selected title after an image was clicked and put it in input text box

  if (event.target != event.currentTarget) {
    let dropdownContent = event.target;
    document.querySelector('#text').value += dropdownContent;
  }
};
```

```html
<div id="myDropdown" class="dropdownContent" onclick="javascript:emoiconsSelect(event);">
  <span title="img1"><img src="images/smilies/1blowkiss.gif"></span>
  <span title="img2"><img src="images/smilies/1blowkiss3.gif"></span>
  <span title="img3"><img src="images/smilies/1blowkiss4.gif"></span>
  <span title="img4"><img src="images/smilies/1blowkissrose.gif"></span>
</div>
```

I can't seem to find much information on doing it this way or even if it can be done this way but I can not use option and select because they do not allow images in combo boxes.

Comment: Note that you've never needed to add `javascript:` before a function name in the `onclick` attribute. It was only needed in the `href` attribute of anchors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's much easier to add a click handler to each of the `<span>` tags and extract its `title` property when clicked:

```js
function emoiconsSelect(elmt) {
    console.log(elmt.title);
}
```

```html
<div id="myDropdown" class="dropdownContent">
    <span title="img1" onclick="javascript:emoiconsSelect(this);"><img src="images/smilies/1blowkiss.gif"></span>
    <span title="img2" onclick="javascript:emoiconsSelect(this);"><img src="images/smilies/1blowkiss3.gif"></span>
    <span title="img3" onclick="javascript:emoiconsSelect(this);"><img src="images/smilies/1blowkiss4.gif"></span>
    <span title="img4" onclick="javascript:emoiconsSelect(this);"><img src="images/smilies/1blowkissrose.gif"></span>
</div>
```